# Calling instance variables inside class methods

Tags: objective-c, class

```
//SecondPage.h
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *secondLabelText;
+(SecondPage *) newAlloc;
+(id) totalOpen;
+(void)setSecondLabelText;

//SecondPage.h
@synthesize secondLabelText;   //DOESNT WORK.
NSString* secondLabelText;   //DOES WORK. 


+(void) setSecondLabelText
{
    secondLabelText = @"TEST";
}

+(id) totalOpen
{
    [self setSecondLabelText];
    return secondLabelText;
}
```

I want to be able to use class methods to 'copy' a class's variable into another class. In this instance I was use [SecondPage totalOpen], but the only problem is that I can only set secondLabelText inside the class method setSecondLabelText, I cannot call it if it's already set. Is there a way I can return an already set value for a class, or a different way to approach what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't access instance variables from class methods. Think about it - it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear on what you're trying to achieve but class methods don't have instances in the sense that you seem to believe. A class method that copied a variable from one instance to another would have to take two instances as arguments. In your code you can access `NSString *secondLabelText` because you've declared it as a **global** variable. It's completely unrelated to the property that each instance of the class has other than that you've confusingly given it the same name.

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve here is this:

class1InstanceVariabe = [class2 classMethod]
So basically in my situation, firstLabelText in class 1 will equal secondLabelText in class2

Comment: Can you talk briefly on why you think class methods rather than ordinary instance methods are the correct thing to use?

Comment: I have tried using instance methods but I haven't been able to achieve my goal (copying class2's variable into class1).

Comment: You need to take a step back and properly learn Object Oriented programming.  The whole point is that instances encapsulate state.  If you need object1 to grab state from object2, then it is up to you to architect your app such that object1 has a reference to object2.  Pushing everything into classes just makes everything a global variable, as Tommy stated.